# Car Radio Installation issues

Tags: electrical, toyota, audio, wiring

I am having a very weird situation with my newly installed Pumpkin Auto radio.

I recently bought the Pumpkin Auto universal radio and I am unable to get it to work on a Toyota Starlet Carat, model 97.

The original Pioneer-Toyota radio has been removed and I have used the same wires to connect the new radio as follows:

The yellow wire to the battery
The red wire to the ACC
The black wire to the ground

Once I put the key on ACC, the new radio turns on, show the booting screen and then powers off.  During this situation, when the radio turns off and power on again (all by itself), the front lights of the car flash.

I have powered the Pumpkin Auto with a 12V input and it works fine.  So, it is confirmed that there is no issue with the radio.

Also, I have checked the battery and the alternator and both seem to be working fine.  The battery gives 12.7V with the engine is off and gives 14.6V when the engine is on.

Is there any reason why the above mentioned situtation may happen?

---update 1---

I was able to power on the radio in the car when I connected the antenna to it.  However, the following issues are noted.

1. When the illumination wire is connected and I try to turn on the low beam light, the 15A fuse (tail) burnt out.

Well, I decided to disconnect the illumination wire.

2. The radio works but now I am unable to turn on the low beam light.  However, the high beam light works.

Comment: Red and black are normally the pos and neg ... should yellow be acc? Do you have the wiring labels on the radio?

Comment: Yes, there is a wiring label on the radio.  The red wire is for ACC and the black wire is the ground wire.  The Yellow wire is for battery (it keeps the configurations when powered off).

Answer (score 1):

Is there a wire on the harness that effects the brightness of the radio? Sometimes there is a wire, and it gets power based on the brightness of cabin lights or the front lights I’m not sure, but if this wire is wrong then maybe that could be the issue!

Comment: There is an illumination wire for the radio.  I have tested with a meter, it gives the negative voltage of the battery when I turn on the light.  Is this normal?

Furthermore, I was able to power on the radio in the car when I connected the antenna to it.  However, the following issues are noted.

1. When the illumination wire is connected and I try to turn on the light, the 15A fuse burnt out.

Well, I decided to disconnect the illumination wire.

2. The radio works but now I am unable to turn on the low beam light.  However, the high beam light works.